# Is it possible to directly return the java.sql.ResultSet from Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I have a Groovy script that is using the `groovy.sql.Sql` class to communicate with the DB, but some legacy Java code is expecting to receive a `java.sql.ResultSet`. Is there any way to execute a `SELECT` query using `groovy.sql.Sql` and directly return the `java.sql.ResultSet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.  One of the main reasons to use Groovy's `Sql` is to automatically handle resources (which is why there are methods using closures to interact with the `ResultSet`, but none that return it -- to ensure they get closed).  I'd strongly recommend revisiting why you are passing around references to `ResultSet` (which could be holding onto server resources) rather than using a POJO/POGO representing those results.

However, if you insist on using `ResultSet`, and you only need few convenience methods, I guess one option would be to copy those methods into your codebase.  As you can see from the [source](https://github.com/apache/incubator-groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-sql/src/main/java/groovy/sql/Sql.java), `Sql` is a pretty thin wrapper over plain old JDBC.  But for what it sounds like you're doing, I question how much value it adds.